# How to 'reverse' the rejection/fulfillment of a promise?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

For a mocha test, I want to assert that a promise will eventually reject.

I don't want to use chai-as-promised. I'd prefer to just use Node's standard assert module, and to just use standard ES6 promises.

The best I've come up with is this, but it feels slightly hacky:

```
it('foo should reject given bad data', function () {
  var rejected;

  return foo('bad data').catch(function (err) {
    rejected = true;
  }).then(function () {
    assert(rejected);
  });
});
```

Can anyone suggest a neater, more expressive way to 'reverse' a promise, so rejection becomes fulfillment and vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just assert on both the resolution and rejection callbacks passing `true` or `false` directly.

```
it('foo should reject given bad data', function () {
  return foo('bad data').then(function () {
      assert(false);
  }, function () {
      assert(true);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using a single `.done()` like so:

```
it('foo should reject given bad data', function () {
  return foo('bad data')
  .done(assert.equal.bind(null, 'false', 'true', null), assert);
});
```

I've used values for `assert.equal` that will provide the equivalent of `assert(false)`, but you can obviously remove the last `null` if you want to print the actual result.

**Edit:** You could actually make this cleaner for multiple tests by defining your own `assertFail` function:

```
function assertFail () { assert(false); }

it('foo should reject given bad data', function () {
  return foo('bad data')
  .done(assertFail, assert);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You may add a reverse method to Promise prototype and then just use it.

```
Promise.prototype.reverse = function() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.then(reject).catch(resolve);
  });
}

foo('bad data')
  .reverse()
  .then(e => assert(true))
  .catch(e => assert(false));
```